# Join integration query involving multiple associations

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I posted this on dba but I am not getting any responses so I added it here.

Here is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88007)

I'd like some assistance in fixing this query. This problem is fairly simple but I'm just not able to solve it. Let me explain the background on what it currently does, and then what I need to integrate.

First, here are my current tables.

**users (performers) table**

the users table lists all users. we are going to assume for this query that all users selected are type performers.

```
users
-----------
id
hash
first_name
last_name
```

here is a dump of the users table:

```
id  hash                              first_name  last_name  
 1  092ee63c6698851ba72183388bff1b3b  Jonathan    Kushner    
 2  2d234affe1d08c3394cd499f297d7380  Dustin      Kushner
```

**aliases table**

the aliases table lists all aliases. we connect this table to performers in a further table.

```
aliases
----------
id
hash
title
```

here is a dump of the aliases table:

```
id  hash             title       
 1  436etgfgdggdd    Greatness
 2  54645655gggdgdg  Mr.Darkness
 3  ffsafsdsfdfdssf  Mr.Shadow
```

**performers_aliases table**

the performers_aliases table connects users of type performers to aliases in the aliases table.

```
performers_aliases
----------
id
hash
performer_id (connects to the users.id column)
alias_id
```

here's a dump of the performers_aliases table:

```
id  hash             performer_id  alias_id  
 1  dsaadsasdadsads             1           1
 2  d4544534553                 2           2
 3  adfasdadsadsa               2           3
```

**videos table**

the videos table lists all videos.

```
videos
----------
id
hash
title
```

here's a dump of the videos table:

```
id  hash                             title       
 1  89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4 crazy sports blooper
```

**videos_performers**

the videos performers table connects videos to a user of type performer.

```
videos_performers
----------
id
hash
video_id
performer_id (connects to the users.id column)
```

heres a dump of the videos performers table:

```
id  hash                              video_id  performer_id  
 1  3a7e0f543af5152c623ad8156079bb73         1               1
 2  c0abf5f50f6382c744a9359d7dbc4c8c         1               2
```

OK. Now let me show you my current query:

```
    SELECT        
      `users`.`first_name`,
      `users`.`last_name`,
      `aliases`.`title` AS `alias`,
      `videos`.`title` AS `video`
    FROM
      `users` 
      LEFT JOIN `performers_aliases` 
        ON `performers_aliases`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `aliases` 
        ON `aliases`.`id` = `performers_aliases`.`alias_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos_performers` 
        ON `videos_performers`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos` 
        ON `videos`.`id` = `videos_performers`.`video_id`  
    WHERE (
        `videos`.`hash` = '89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4'
      ) 
    ORDER BY `users`.`last_name` ASC
```

This query does the following:

- selects users who are performers for a video. we need to include the aliases tables to grab the performers aliases. (note: performers can have multiple aliases)

Here's a resultset:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Shadow    crazy sports blooper
```

**As you can see, this video contains 2 performers - Jonathan Kushner and Dustin Kushner. However, Dustin has 2 aliases so it has 2 records for him**

**What I'd like to do is incorporate having video performers connected via aliases to videos, so instead of having 2 records for Dustin since he has 2 aliases, it would only connect to the alias being used for that specific video.**

For example, the output for this video would be:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
```

This resultset shows only 2 records now, one for Dustin as Mr.Darkness and one for Jonathan as Greatness. You'll note that no longer there exists a record for Dustin as Mr.Shadow since Mr.Shadow was not used as the alias for that video.

Here's my current work as to how to I think about solving this. I've created a `videos_performers_aliases` table that connects videos to performers to aliases.
I don't think I need the performer_id column but id like it anyway. What I believe is important is the video to alias connection.

```
videos_performers_aliases
--------------------
id
hash
video_id
performer_id
alias_id
```

Here is a dump of the videos_performers_aliases table:

```
    id  hash                   video_id  performer_id  alias_id         
     1  fdsa97asd987das7das97         1             1         1  
     2  dfdfsdfsfdsdfsdfsfd           1             2         2
```

And then I would modify the query from above as follows:

```
    SELECT        
      `users`.`first_name`,
      `users`.`last_name`,
      `aliases`.`title` AS `alias`,
      `videos`.`title` AS `video`
    FROM
      `users` 
      LEFT JOIN `performers_aliases` 
        ON `performers_aliases`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `aliases` 
        ON `aliases`.`id` = `performers_aliases`.`alias_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos_performers` 
        ON `videos_performers`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos` 
        ON `videos`.`id` = `videos_performers`.`video_id`
      LEFT JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
        ON `videos_performers_aliases`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`
    WHERE (
        `videos`.`hash` = '89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4'
      ) 
    ORDER BY `users`.`last_name` ASC
```

As you can see, i added this to the query:

```
LEFT JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
        ON `videos_performers_aliases`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`
```

I'd like my output to be the following:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
```

This insinuates that we have one performer as Mr.Darkness and one performer as Greatness. As you can see, Mr.Shadow is not in the resultset.

Unfortunately, the resultset here is still:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Shadow    crazy sports blooper
```

This is as far as I've gotten on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the current contents of the `videos_performers_aliases` table?  Please add them to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90b260 and then edit above to include this link. It will be very helpful for anyone else visiting this, to distill the lengthy post you have above.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski done.

Comment: You have several LEFT JOINs, and that is actually part of your problem. If the video `89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4` has no associated performers, do you want to return NULLs for the `first_name, last_name, alias`, or do you want no row returned?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i do not want any rows returned if there are no associated performers. i dont see why any of my left joins are unneccessary, they are all connected pieces to the query.

Comment: Gotcha. I think I've got the right solutions then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece in the way you had expressed the query is another condition in the `videos_perfomers_aliases` join, to join it to both the `videos.id` and the `aliases.id` tables.

```
LEFT JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
  ON `videos_performers_aliases`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`
  AND `videos_performers_aliases`.`alias_id` = `aliases`.id`
```

However, using a `LEFT JOIN` there will actually cause both aliases to be returned. Instead using an `INNER JOIN` will return only the connected alias.

```
INNER JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
  ON `videos_performers_aliases`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`
  AND `videos_performers_aliases`.`alias_id` = `aliases`.id`
```

Here's your version modified to produce the intended result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec26c/21

#### Better, with fewer joins:

But the entire query can be simplified. Because `videos_performers_aliases` includes both video and alias information already, it renders the `videos_performers` table unnecessary for this query (and maybe others).  You can execute this entire query with this chain:

```
users(id) --> (performer_id)performers_aliases(alias_id) --> (id)aliases(id) --> (alias_id)videos_performers_aliases(video_id) --> (id)videos
```

It is therefore possible to eliminate one of the joins, and simplify the join condition with `videos_performers_aliases` to require just one part.

```
SELECT
  `users`.`first_name`,
  `users`.`last_name`,
  `aliases`.`title` AS alias,
  `videos`.`title` AS video
FROM
  `users` 
  LEFT JOIN `performers_aliases` 
    ON `performers_aliases`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `aliases` 
    ON `aliases`.`id` = `performers_aliases`.`alias_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
    ON videos_performers_aliases.alias_id = aliases.id
  LEFT JOIN `videos`
    ON `videos`.id = videos_performers_aliases.video_id
WHERE (
  `videos`.`hash` = '89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4'
) 
ORDER BY `users`.`last_name` ASC
```

Here it is in action, producing your expected result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec26c/19

About `videos_performers_aliases`, you said:

> I don't think I need the `performer_id` column but id like it anyway. What I believe is important is the video to alias connection.

That assessment is correct. The connection is only needed between `videos` and `aliases` because you can join to `users` via `performers_aliases`.  It isn't harmful to keep it, except that if for some reason you must reassign an alias, it means updating the `performer_id` in more than one related table.  Just something to keep in mind -- I suspect you've already considered it though.

Comment: @jkushner My pleasure. Good luck.